# Marshal a variable from C# to void* in native C++ and change the variable value in Managed/C# inside native program

Tags: c#, c++, interop, marshalling

I have this C++ code :

```
void ReleaseHandle(void* handle){
  Machine.motor motor =static_cast<Machine.IMotor*> (handle)
  if (motor == 0) throw;
  delete motor;
  handle = nullptr;
}
```

so far I can pass a variable into Releasehandle using PInvoke in Managed using uint as data type, problem is the value of passed variable doesn't change. This method is not the whole package, but i think this is enough to illustrate what i want to do. I need the value to change since if the pointer doesn't change in managed side and i decide to call releaseHandle again from managed, it will throw stacktrace since the releaseHandle is called and machine is not found (released).

I have tried a lot of methods of passing datatype as ref from managed including but not limited to :

- void*
- [In, Out] void*
- uint
- ref/out uint
- ref/out void*
- UintPtr
- ref/out UintPtr

I expect when i call ReleaseHandle in managed like

```
uint managedHandle = 123213124;
ReleaseHandle(managedHandle);
Console.WriteLine(managedHandle); // this outputs to 0
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It might help if you could describe what it is you are trying to do. I.e. why do you want to change the pointer value?

Comment: This isn't "C/C++" code (no such language exists), but C++ code. Removing the C tag.

Comment: You would need to write `ReleaseHandle()` like this: `void ReleaseHandle(void** handle){  *handle = nullptr;}` - note the use of "pointer-to-pointer" `**`. You would also have to update the P/Invoke declaration accordingly, probably using `ref IntPtr handle`.

Comment: The operation you want to do C++-side is quite useless. You aren't really freeing memory. If you simply want to reset a pointer, you can do it C#-side.

Comment: nullptr is zero so won't you always get a zero after method is called?

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is, that you are intending to change the a variable you pass by value.

That having said, as [Matthew Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106159/matthew-watson) pointed out in the comment to your question, you have to adjust the interface of the method you are calling in the DLL to take a pointer pointing to the location of the pointer you want to modify.

In your example you need to pass the pointer to `managedHandle` to `ReleaseHandle`.

Hence your code should look like this in your DLL:

```
void ReleaseHandle(void** handle) {
    *handle = nullptr; /* Note that here we dereference one level 
                          to modify the content of the location 
                          pointed at */
}
```

In your C# program on the other hand, you should import the function with something like that:

```
[DllImport("YourLibrary.dll")]
static extern void ReleaseHandle(ref IntPtr handle);
```

and invoke it by using the `ref` keyword:

```
IntPtr value = IntPtr.Add(IntPtr.Zero, 123456789);
ReleaseHandle(ref managedHandle);
Console.WriteLine(managedHandle); // this outputs to 0
```